# Deep link only subdomains to my app

Tags: android, intentfilter

My company has a "landing" website that present its product : `http://brandname.com`. The product I try to port to Android is found at `http://subdomain.brandname.com` where `subdomain` is different for each client.

So I need to deeplink subdomain.brandname.com (where subdomain can be anything) to my Android app but not brandname.com. => fr.brandname.com is the french version of the "landing" website and therefore shall be excluded from the matched url (as 'es','it'....)

How should I do that ?

One more question : I want to add the playstore url of my app as intent filter too. How shall I proceed ? Is there a way to includes the GET arguments in the filter ?

Thanks !

Comment: I know this is late but, is the subdomain dynamic or do you know about it before hand?

Comment: hello, no pb for the delay, It's all dynamic, each new client will get its own subdomain. But all the url I must not match are known.

Comment: I've same problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40783464/android-deep-link-app-chooser-is-triggered-for-each-subdomain/50836072#50836072 Anyone has an idea? :)

Comment: It seems that the solution is to generate the manifest through a gradle script and include it in your CI so that it's updated each time you push a new build on the store.
To my knowledge there is no way to do real *.domain matching.

Comment: *.domain matching is possible, see: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations.html#multi-subdomain