# Android deep link: App chooser is triggered for each subdomain

Tags: android, deep-linking

So I have an app with deep linking that can open links from the company website. 
I do this by adding an `intent-filter` to an Activity tag like so:

```
        <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="*.company.com"
            android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
```

The problem is that the website has multiple subdomains that each trigger the app chooser. (`category1.company.com`, `category2.company.com` etc)

If it were using only one domain, the app chooser would appear only once when opening the main page, the user would choose to continue in the browser "just once" and navigate the website without interruption.

With subdomains, each time the user navigates to a different subdomain he sees the app chooser and has to click "just once" again.

Is there any way to configure the app to display the app chooser only the first time you go on that domain and not for each subdomain?

Comment: see trying to change  `android:host="*.company.com"` to  `android:host="company.com"`

Comment: try adding android:pathPrefix="/yourpath" in <data .. > . This link may help.. http://search-codelabs.appspot.com/codelabs/android-deep-linking#2

Comment: `android:host="company.com` has the same effect

Comment: @Baba I don't see how adding a pathPrefix helps. I don't want to be more specific with the url filter.

Answer (score 2):

Have you try several data block in the same intent filter

```
   <data
        android:host="category1.company.com"
        android:scheme="https" />
   <data
        android:host="category2.company.com"
        android:scheme="https" />
```

....

Comment: We have a few subdomains so I would try to avoid adding them all

Comment: Also this doesn't change the behavior. App picker dialog is still displayed while navigating between subdomains.

Answer (score 0):

use [app-ink](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links) instead, so android will not ask and just open your app.
you can use a wildcard since Android 6 to include all subdomains.

https://developer.android.com/training/app-links